# Deploying not happening in publishing process

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am trying to publish to local file system, however publishing is not happening properly and its failed to deploy in my 2011 GA VM environment.

I am getting "**Polling for notification for destination: YTnMgU6u5Vh09cOGUG7ouA== has exceeded polling attempts for transaction: tcm:0-121257-66560**" error in "Preparing Deployment" stage.

I have used the “Local File System” protocol in my publication target and I have provided path like **d:\tridion\publish.**

And I have provided the same path in **cd_storage_conf.xml** under the **<storage type=”filesystem”>**. All other storage types are commented.

And in **cd_deployer_conf.xml** , **quee location path is c:\tridion\incoming**.

When I publish any page into my publication target, the zipped package is placed in the d:\tridion\publish and it’s not deployed.

Do I need to do any other thing to deploy the zipped package?

Comment: Do you have a deployer service running? Is it reading from the incoming folder? Is there a cd_core log or cd_deployer log with errors?

Comment: Shouldn't the path for the Local File System protocol and the Deployer queue location be the same? At the moment your package is being created somewhere the Deployer isn't monitoring.

Comment: @@Quirijn: I dont have the deployer service in the VM. At the same time in my VM some other publication targets are there and those are using https protocol and they are storing the contents in the broker db. the zipped package is placed in the path what i give in the publication target only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your working sites use HTTP sender/deployer. In that scenario your deployer is triggered  by the HTTP servlet which receives the transport package.

When you use local file system - you **MUST** configure your deployer to work in a different way. It has to run as some form of background service. Typically on a windows box this means installing the deployer as a windows service. Keep in mind that this will then probably have additional config files for the deployer and broker/storage.

Answer (score 6):

The path provided in the `cd_deployer_conf.xml` (the one you specify in `Queue/Location`!!!) needs to be the same one you provide in your publication target (in your case you have in the publicationTarget some path on D drive while in the deployer conf you have another one from C drive). Then you also need make sure that your deployer is initialized. You can easily determine if your deployer is initialized by looking if the `meta.xml` is regenerated in the deployer incoming folder.

Not sure if this is relavant but you might be interested also in how to install the deployer: [as a .NET WebSite](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_663JDNNNDHDH889595JDJDJD), [as a Java WebSite](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_884JHJFHFH7745522929JDJHFHFH) or [Windows Service](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_149E726BA4E34D36A70A09F5A5204248)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Daniel: As you said, i have provided the same path in my publication target and cd_deployer_conf.xml. when i publish the page, the zip packgae is placed in the queue location. but that zip package is not deployed in the storage location what i mentioned in the cd_storage_conf.xml. at the same time i dont see any meta.xml in the zip package. and i dont see any deploye service running under the windows service. and i dont have the cd_deployer.exe also in my vm. But at the same time i dont understand how the other publication targets are working and how it is publishing to broker data base.

Comment: Hi there. If it works for other publication targets (and if they are similar to this one) and if you do not have any Deployer service then you probably have the Upload WebApplication installed somewhere on your computer. Check if you have any interesting WebApp in your IIS or else deployed on your WebApplication Server.

Comment: Yes Daniel, I have seen some upload application is there in IIS. I dont know what is happening there.. However, do you have any insignt how i need to publish into my local file system. And i have one more query in cd_storage_conf.xml all the storage location is commented except the local file system. i dont understand how the item is published to broker db using other publication targets.